# how to identify specific sequences (round-trips) in a pandas dataset?

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, finance

I have a simple, yet challenging algorithmic problem to solve.

I have a dataset at the trader - stock - day level, and I want to identify the round-trips in the data. Round-trips are just specific sequences in the data. That is, if you cumulate over time the holding position of stock s for individual i, a round-trip starts and ends with a zero net holding position.

An example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'trader' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a'],
              'stock' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b'],
              'day' :[0,1,2,4,5,10,1],
              'delta':[10,-10,15,-10,-5,5,6],
              'cumq' : [10,0,15,5,0,5,6] ,
              'tag': [1,1,2,2,2,0,0]})
```

output

```
 Out[15]: 
   cumq  day  delta stock  tag trader
0    10    0     10     a    1      a
1     0    1    -10     a    1      a
2    15    2     15     a    2      a
3     5    4    -10     a    2      a
4     0    5     -5     a    2      a
5     5   10      5     a    0      a
6     6    1      6     b    0      a
```

Here, you can see that trader `a` has bought two stocks (`a` and `b`). `delta` corresponds to the quantity purchased or sold on a given day. So you can see that we have two full round-trips on `stock a` (-10 +10 = 0 ) and (+15 - 10 -5 =0) and two non-completed round-trips (+5 on `stock a`, and +6 on `stock b`).

I would like to be able to create a variable `tag` that tells me this. That is, a variable that is 0 whenever a round-trip is not terminated, and that takes the values 1, 2, 3 for the first, second, third, etc round-trip identified in a given stock-trader combination.

Any idea how to do that in an efficient way?
Many thanks!

EDIT:

- short sales are possible. For instance sell 10, buy 25, sell 25 and buy 10 would be one round trip.
- a round-trip can be implemented during the same day: in that case the delta will be zero (indeed, you buy and sell the same quantity that day). This means that several daily round-trip can follow each other in the data. So the 0 boundaries for the round-trips are inclusive. Example: you buy 10 and sell 10 today (delta = 0), then you buy 15 and sell 15 tomorrow (delta = 0 again). These correspond to two different consecutive round-trips

PROPOSED SOLUTION - SEEMS TO WORK - VERY SLOW

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'trader' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a'],'stock' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b'], 'day' :[0,1,2,4,5,10,1],'delta':[10,-10,15,-10,-5,5,0] ,'out': [1,1,2,2,2,0,1]})

def proc_trader(_df):
    _df['tag'] = np.nan
    # make every ending of a roundtrip with its index
    _df['tag'][df.cumq == 0] = range(1, (_df.cumq == 0).sum() + 1)
    # backfill the roundtrip index until previous roundtrip;
    # then fill the rest with 0s (roundtrip incomplete for most recent trades)
    _df['tag'] = _df['tag'].fillna(method = 'bfill').fillna(0)
    return _df

df.sort_values(by=['trader', 'stock','day'], inplace=True)
df['cumq']=df.groupby(['trader', 'stock']).delta.transform('cumsum')
df = df.groupby(['trader', 'stock']).apply(proc_trader)
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks!!!!

Comment: How do you treat short sales? If allowed, what would be the output of a trader that bought 10 and sold 20 the following day?

Comment: short sales would be starting with a minus. say you sell 10 and then you buy 10. thats perfectly legit

Comment: But what if crossed in the same day? Do you force a zero and have duplicate days, or do just show net change on the day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'trader' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a'],'stock' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b'], 'day' :[0,1,2,4,5,10,1],'delta':[10,-10,15,-10,-5,5,6], 'cumq' : [10,0,15,5,0,6,11] ,'tag': [1,1,2,2,2,0,0]})

def proc_trader(_df):
    if _df.shape[0] == 1:
        _df['tag'] = _df['delta'] == 0
        return _df

    _df['tag'] = np.nan
    # make every ending of a roundtrip with its index
    _df['tag'][df.cumq == 0] = range(1, (df.cumq == 0).sum() + 1)
    # backfill the roundtrip index until previous roundtrip;
    # then fill the rest with 0s (roundtrip incomplete for most recent trades)
    _df['tag'] = _df['tag'].fillna(method = 'bfill').fillna(0)
    return _df

df = df.groupby(['trader', 'stock']).apply(proc_trader)
```

The idea is that each trader's record is comprised of a series of roundtrips except possible in the end; this assumes something about how zero-delta periods should be counted. We detect all ends of roundtrip periods, backprop the index and fill the rest with 0s.

Comment: thanks but I get `ValueError: Length of replacements must equal series length when I run your code`

Comment: My mistake. I checked `groupby('trader')` but not `groupby(['trader', 'stock'])`. This edit should work for the above example. The error came from group size being 1 (a trader performs a single transaction per a given security).

Comment: Hi Yakym, apparently I still have the same problem. Please see my edited post.

Comment: I think there were some typos in the code: `df` instead of `_df`. Please see my edited post.